# Using string.prototype.replace with a regexp and a function

Tags: javascript, regex

The following returns 'entiy'. I want it to return 'entity'. How can I achieve this?

```
'entities '.replace(/\w(ies)(?:[\W|$|_])+/g, 'y');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just capture the character before the "ies":

```
'entities '.replace(/(\w)(ies)(?:[\W|$|_])+/g, '$1y');
```

Now your question asked about using a function; you can do that too:

```
'entities '.replace(/(\w)(ies)(?:[\W|$|_])+/g, function(_, before, repl) {
  return before + "y";
});
```

I don't know what you want to do with the subsequent stuff after "ies"; you can either capture it and glue it back into the replacement, or else use positive look-ahead. Portions of the input text matched by look-ahead are not part of the match involved with the replacement operation. In other words, the look-ahead does succeed or fail based on the pattern, but the characters matched are not made part of the "to be replaced" grouping.

Comment: Why even bother capturing the character before?

Comment: what about `[\W|$|_]` ?

Comment: @Gavin ?? because he doesn't want to lose it. The `.replace()` function expects to replace the whole match.

Comment: @PranavCBalan: It's inside a positive lookahead, the character is not "consumed".

Comment: @PranavCBalan I don't know what the OP wants to do with that part; the code in the question throws it away.

Comment: @FelixKling : it's non-capturing group.. not positive lookahead

Comment: @PranavCBalan: Oh you are right :-/ Sorry for that.

Comment: @Pointy I understand that. I just wasn't thinking of the case that 'ies' might not be preceded but another character, and would then be replaced with just 'y'.

Comment: @Pointy :  it can be more optimized , `'entities '.replace(/(\w)ies(?:[\W_]+|$)/g, '$1y');`

Comment: @PranavCBalan yes that would work too. I was caught up wondering what the OP was thinking about that involved using a function so I just left that part alone.

Comment: Accepted because my original ques was about how to use the function variant, even though I used @4castle's answer in the end.

Answer (score 3):

You could change the `\w` to `\B` to verify that there is not a word boundary.

```js
console.log('entities '.replace(/\Bies\b/g, 'y'));
```

Comment: How can I get `'entities'.replace(/\B(ies)(?:[\W|$|_])+/g, 'y')` to return `entity`? Note the loss of the trailing space.

Comment: @BenAston What exactly do you want the regex to do? You could just call `trim()` to remove the trailing space.

Comment: `'entities'.replace(/\B(ies)(?:[\W|$|_])+/g, 'y')` does not work in the case when `ies` is at the end of the string. Why? (I thought the `$` would cover this case) Your revised answer works great.

Comment: @BenAston The character class `[\W|$|_]` isn't allowing for the end of the string, it's matching a literal `$` character.